# Customization options for Buildship for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

We are currently using Spring STS Gradle for Eclipse and it works great. But since there is a new plugin coming from Gradle team I wanted to try it out.

STS Gradle integration executes Gradle tasks, it's not using Gradle tooling API. This is really good design decision:

- you can generate eclipse project from command line or import project using wizard in Eclipse and result is the same
- you can customize Eclipse Gradle Tasks, so that every developer has the same code formatting rules, find bugs, check style, capabilities and so on ....

No comes a part where I'm a bit fuzzy.... It looks to me that Buildship uses Tooling API instead of executing Gradle tasks. Both implementation are coming from Gradle team, so why not reuse already existing tasks?

Is this close integration with eclipse so important, that we have to give up possibility for customization?

I know - this sounds more like rhetorical question. But I would really like to understand the reason for such decision. Missing customization possibilities are no-go for many potential users.